# Are there expressions which have no inverse Laplace?

Tags: laplace-transform

For a function $f(t)$ to have a Laplace transform, it must be piece-wise continuous of exponential order. But what about the inverse Laplace ?

Is there expression $F(s)$ which has no inverse Laplace ? If so, what are the necessary conditions to have inverse Laplace ?

I'm asking because I was working on this problem to find its inverse Laplace:

$$F(s)=\ln\left(\frac{s+4}{(s-1)(s^2+1)}\right)$$

And here what I got:

$$F(s)=\ln\left(\frac{s+4}{(s-1)(s^2+1)}\right)=\ln(s+4)-\ln(s-1)-\ln(s^2+1)$$
$$F'(s)=\frac{1}{s+4}-\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{2s}{s^2+1}$$
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F'(s))=e^{-4t}-e^{t}-2\cos{t}$$

Knowing that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s))=\frac{-1}{t}\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F'(s))$:

$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s))=\frac{-1}{t}(e^{-4t}-e^{t}-2\cos{t})$$

But, I tried to check this result and found that:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{-1}{t}(e^{-4t}-e^{t}-2\cos{t})=D.N.E$$

Which means that I can't find Laplace transform for $f(t)$

So, if my procedure is wrong or there are some expressions which have no inverse Laplace ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: you need the Fourier transform (of distributions) for answering those kind of questions, and the answer is that it depends on how you define the Laplace transform. I'd say you need $F(s)= \frac{1}{H_c(s)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f \ast h_c(t) e^{-st} dt$ to converge and be analytic on some strip $a < Re(s) < b$ for any Gaussian $h_c(t) = e^{-c^2 t^2}$. Then you can define the inverse Laplace transform as $\sigma \in (a,b), \ \ f(t) = \lim_{c \to 0}\frac{1}{2i \pi}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma-i\infty} F(s)H_c(s) e^{st} ds$ where the $\lim$ is in the sense of distributions...

Comment: I didn't study Fourier transform yet, so I don't fully understand your answer. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

There are expressions which are not Laplace transforms of functions of exponential order.  A necessary condition for $F(s)$ to be the Laplace transform of a function of exponential order is that $|s F(s)|$ is bounded as $s \to +\infty$.  Your function has
$|F(s)| \sim -2 \ln(s)$ as $s \to +\infty$.

However, your $F$ is the Laplace transform of a distribution that is not a function.

Comment: Could you please refer me to some source to read more about this condition ? Thanks :)

Comment: @MohamedMostafa in case you were still interested: https://sites.oxy.edu/ron/math/341/10/ws/25.pdf